# Python sklearn RandomForestClassifier non-reproducible results

Tags: python, machine-learning, random, random-forest, reproducible-research

I've been using sklearn's random forest, and I've tried to compare several models. Then I noticed that random-forest is giving different results even **with the same** seed. I tried it both ways: random.seed(1234) as well as use random forest built-in random_state = 1234
In both cases, I get non-repeatable results. What have I missed...?

```
# 1
random.seed(1234)
RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, max_features=5, criterion='gini', min_samples_leaf = 10)
# or 2
RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=5, max_features=5, criterion='gini', min_samples_leaf = 10, random_state=1234)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!!

EDIT:
Adding a more complete version of my code

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=60, max_features=60, \
                        criterion='entropy', \
                        min_samples_leaf = 3, random_state=seed)
# As describe, I tried random_state in several ways, still diff results
clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

predicted = clf.predict(X_test)
predicted_prob = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(np.array(y_test), predicted_prob)
auc = metrics.auc(fpr,tpr)
print (auc)
```

EDIT: It's been quite a while, but I *think* using [RandomState](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html) might solve the problem. I didn't test it yet myself, but if you're reading it, it's worth a shot. Also, it is generally preferable to use RandomState instead of random.seed().

Comment: Did you also call the same random seed before the second time you call Random Forest Classifier? Can you show your different results also?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer addresses your question

Comment: The first time I ran (1) for several times, and calculated predict and ROC/AUC. gave different result each time. Then I did the same, using method (2), still, results weren't reproducible. Then I used the 3rd method, as @sera suggested, still, no joy. For all other methods (logistic regression, LDA, naive-bayes) I get the exact same results to the dot.

Comment: Some examples: under the same seed got AUC of: 0.779396, 0.794945

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First make sure that you have the latest versions of the needed modules(e.g. scipy, numpy etc). **When** you type `random.seed(1234)`, you use the `numpy` generator.

---

When you use `random_state` parameter inside the `RandomForestClassifier`, there are several options: **int**, **RandomState instance** or **None**.

---

From the docs [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) :

- If int, random_state is the seed used by the random number generator;
- If RandomState instance, random_state is the random number generator;
- If None, the random number generator is the RandomState instance used by np.random.

---

**A way to use the same generator in both cases is the following.** I use the same (numpy) generator in both cases and **I get reproducible results** (same results in both cases).

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from numpy import *

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
                       n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                       random_state=0, shuffle=False)

random.seed(1234)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2)
clf.fit(X, y)

clf2 = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state = random.seed(1234))
clf2.fit(X, y)
```

**Check if the results are the same:**

```
all(clf.predict(X) == clf2.predict(X))
#True
```

---

### Check after running the same code for 5 times:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from numpy import *

for i in range(5):

    X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
                       n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                       random_state=0, shuffle=False)

    random.seed(1234)
    clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2)
    clf.fit(X, y)

    clf2 = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state = random.seed(1234))
    clf2.fit(X, y)

    print(all(clf.predict(X) == clf2.predict(X)))
```

**Results:**

```
True
True
True
True
True
```

Comment: I tried both ways listed above. In addition I also tried the one you wrote with random_state = random_seed(1234). All methods give non-repeatable results for both random forest and decision tree. Each time I run it, with the same seed, the results are different

Comment: I have run the code I posted 100 times and I always get `True` when I ckeck using: `all(clf.predict(X) == clf2.predict(X))`

Comment: Yes. I reviewed the question again after a long time, and found my mistake (related to using RandomState()). After doing that everything worked correctly

Comment: perfect. please consider upvoting my answer

Comment: This didn't work. But this did work: `RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state = 1)`

Comment: @There I just re-run my code and all sanity checks pass. Make sure you do not overwrite variables. Also share somehow your code to help more.

Comment: I'd suggest testing something more rigorous than just the predictions on `X`; if the dataset is too easy, together with predicting on the training set, and checking only the hard class predictions, could coincidentally come out equal. Using a test set and comparing `predict_proba` would be a bit nicer.