# How to predict manually in Random Forest Regressor in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random-forest

I have this Random forest model
where X_train, X_test as well as y_train, y_test are numpy arrays of shape of (1,n) and (1,m)
i.e. input consists of only one feature

```py
model_1 = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=50,random_state=42)
model_1.fit(X_train.reshape(-1,1), y_train.reshape(-1,1))
print(model_1.score(X_test.reshape(-1,1), y_test.reshape(-1,1)))
```

which works totally fine to fit training data and then also gives a score of around 0.95 respectively for test data but now if I want to predict for

```py
future = np.array([int(i) for i in range(len(X)+1,len(X)+11)])
```

so future is

```py
array([155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164])
```

I did this :

```py
model_1.predict(future.reshape(-1, 1))
```

But in the output I got all same values

```py
array([2985.02, 2985.02, 2985.02, 2985.02, 2985.02, 2985.02, 2985.02,
       2985.02, 2985.02, 2985.02])
```

Can somebody tell me why I am getting all predictions to be a same number ?
and this is just not happening for 10 future values but even for 100 values.
Is there any other way to predict results manually ?

Comment: What happens when you try preditcting for **test data**? I mean what is the result of `model_1.predict(X_test.reshape(-1,1))`?

Comment: @büşraçelik for X_test output is not a same number

Comment: Could you put a small example (perhaps with _m_ and _n_ being less than 5 or less than 10) for `{X|y}_train` and `{X|y}_test` that would show the problem? I don't know if that would involve restructuring your whole model, but if it doesn't, it would help to be able to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the means to try running code, but it sounds like a random-number-generator seed doesn't get changed. Often, the type of repeatability/reproducibility you've described is desired, as in [this SO situation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47433920/6505499) - it helps to test certain things. In that example, the OP is concerned because the results are *not* reproducible.

The first thing to look at, I think, is the `random_state = 42`. You might be able to find there if the same random seed is used each time.

As for **predicting the result** (if that means that you want to predict the "same number" you're getting each time, you'll need to find the (**P**seudo**R**andom **N**umber **G**enerator ([PRNG, wikipedia article linked here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)).

Actually, that article has a nice description of what you might be running into:

> The PRNG-generated sequence is not truly random, because it is completely determined by an initial value, called the PRNG's seed.

You'll need to look through the source code. Hopefully, someone commented their code well enough that it will be easy to find. Look for words such as *seed*, *generator*, and possible other words from the wiki article.

Once again, without being able to try things out or being able to see the source code, *I can't tell you this is the actual problem*. However, it reminds me of a simulation we messed up during grad school. The goal was to run a particle-collision simulator for something on the order of 10^12 events; we didn't reset the seed, so we had about 10^12 *identical* simulations. That didn't help with the statistics we were trying to do.