# Why do two random forest models give different results on the same data

Tags: python, random-forest

I ran random forest on the same data, and I got different results. According to [this article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/different-results-each-time-in-machine-learning/#:%7E:text=You%20will%20get%20different%20results%20when%20you%20run%20the%20same,of%20the%20machine%20learning%20algorithm.&text=Variance%3A%20How%20sensitive%20the%20algorithm,specific%20data%20used%20during%20training),  the reason in is:

> You can get different results when you run the same algorithm on the same data due to the nature of the learning algorithm. Some algorithms are not deterministic; instead, they are stochastic. This means that their behavior incorporates elements of randomness.

And then it's mentioned that we can handle it by:

> you set the seed used by the pseudorandom number generator to ensure that each time the algorithm is run, it gets the same randomness.

I am not sure how can I control the pseudorandom number in this case?
Also I use a random state while shuffling my dataframe, thus will ensure that the shuffling will be done in the same way every time, but it has nothing to do with controlling the model by seudorandom number generator. right?

```
df = df.sample(frac=1,random_state = 524).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Are you using scikit-learn? Can you provide some sample code showing how you are training the random forest model?

Answer (score 1):

There are three random elements. The first two are part of the algorithm. The las depends on the data.

When you declare your classifier, in `RandomForestClassifier` there's:

1. The shuffling of the data when a new tree is trained
2. The shuffling of the features picked at random when building each node

These two are controlled by setting a random seed before fitting your model: `RandomForestClassifier(random_state=123)`

When you fit your data:
3. The training data you pass to `.fit()`

You have the third source of randomness controlled. So set a `random_state` to make both models converge to the exact same results.

Answer (score 1):

To get reproducible results you should fix your `random_state` at various stages:

1. When splitting the dataset
2. When initialising Random Forest

Here is a toy example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
diabetes = load_diabetes(as_frame = True)

X = diabetes['data']
y = diabetes['target']
# control randomness when splitting
X_train,X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size = 0.1, random_state = 42)
# control randomness at initialisation
rfr = RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 42)
rfr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = rfr.predict(X_test)
```

If you were to rerun this cell multiple times, `y_pred` will always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the same as the one stated here : [Python sklearn RandomForestClassifier non-reproducible results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433920/python-sklearn-randomforestclassifier-non-reproducible-results)

So you might be able to get reproducible results by adding

```
random.seed(1234)
```

(with any value that you would like between the parentheses) before
you run the random forest classifier.

Also, it is not really important to have different results with machine learning. You should just check that you get coherent results and maybe estimate an error margin (via simulations).