# RandomForestClassifier can't give me repdoucible results

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, random-forest, random-seed

My issue is that even though I implemented a Random_state for the `RandomForestClassifier` itself and for the Train-Test-Split (even I don't think this isn't necessary there because I am working with the `shuffle = False` - due to Time Series Data). Please find below my code and I already tried the solution for the following question but it didn't worked: [Python sklearn RandomForestClassifier non-reproducible results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433920/python-sklearn-randomforestclassifier-non-reproducible-results)

```
Data Split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False, random_state=13)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = np.array(X_train), np.array(X_test), np.array(y_train), np.array(y_test) 

print(f"Train and Test Size {len(X_train)}, {len(X_test)}")
```

Random  Forest Classifier

```
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1, 
                                class_weight=cwts(df), 
                                max_depth = 5, 
                                random_state = random.seed(1234))
forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

My y-variable are 1 or 0 for the time series data because I am programing a trading strategy that can only go flat or long. Furthemore, in the next step I am using the BorutaPy wrapper and when looking for the best possible features it always changes the best features because the `RandomForestClassifier` isn't constant. Any of you guys know the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The function `numpy.random.seed` sets a seed for numpy calculations, but returns `None`, so you haven't actually set a fixed seed for consecutive runs of the classifier. Just use an integer for `random_state`.

Comment: I tried to implement it with

`forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1, class_weight=cwts(df), max_depth = 5, random_state = 42)
forest.fit(X_train, y_train)`

but it still changes the result every time I run the code.

Comment: @user14334602 It might warrant a new question, but can you provide a minimal reproducible example? Either a small sample of your data, or using one of sklearn's builtin datasets?